# Add Avatar to blogspot

Tags: support, flair

Is it possible to add the Stack Overflow avatar with the 
username, etc., etc. onto blogspot?

I tried using the iframe:

```
<iframe height="60" width="210" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0"
                    scrolling="no" src="http://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/168703.html"></iframe>
```

But publishing does not display a single thing.

Comment: It works just fine for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Click on "Add a gadget"
2. Click on "HTML/Javascript"
3. Then paste in the iframe code